# “The system is running in low-graphics mode” Error. Solutions won't work,

Tags: 14.04, unity, graphics

I'm currently having problems fixing my ubuntu 16.04 desktop.

I'm currently having problems like this: [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I try running failsafeX but that failed. My next bet was opening terminal (ctrl + lt + f1) and run sudo apt-get install gdm or sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop but install is not working and neither are sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install --fix-missing.

It's all can't find this or can't do this errors.

Comment: Did it ever work on this computer? What video card does it use?

Comment: I found out it's caused by no connection. How to connect to with a username and password thru terminal. @marc

Comment: Please [edit] and post hardware specs, namely the graphics card. That's what you should be troubleshooting right now. BTW, the answers in the linked question are outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled it. That fixed it for me...